# How can I configure my Grunt.js file to copy a directory without a particular subdirectory during the build?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Given that the Gruntfile is located in parent/aurora/Gruntfile.js,

I'd like to configure Grunt to do the following when the build command is executed:

- copy the entire project directory into parent/build/aurora EXCEPT /parent/aurora/node_modules
- once the directory haas been copied, create a zip file and delete the directory

https://github.com/antonpug/aurora/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to copy files or a directory you can just preface the files you don't want to include with `!`. For example, if you don't want to copy a directory just use: `!/parent/aurora/node_modules/**`.

In your grunt task:

```
files: [ 
      { 
        src: ['your_files', '!/parent/aurora/node_modules/**'], 
        dest: 'output/folder'
      }
   ]
```

Hope this helps!